# Cannot specify include file with make and MinGW

Tags: gcc, makefile

I'm facing an issue with a simple makefile and gcc (MinGW with Windows 10).
This is my simple makefile

```
IJNI=-I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\include"
IJNIWIN32=-I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\include/win32"
CC=gcc

default:    main

main:   lowlevelAccess.o
    $(CC) $(IJNI) $(IJNIWIN32) -c lowlevelAccess -o lowlevelAccess.o
```

When from a command promp I launch make, I obtain:

```
gcc    -c -o lowlevelAccess.o lowlevelAccess.c
lowlevelAccess.c:7:17: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
 #include <jni.h>
             ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [lowlevelAccess.o] Error 1
```

What is wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't adding your `-I` flags on the `lowlevelAccess.o` compilation but that's the rule that needs it (not the linking rule where you have it now).

Try adding `CFLAGS += $(IJNI) $(IJNIWIN32)` to your makefile (possibly use `CPPFLAGS` instead I'm not sure offhand which is technically more correct here).

See [Variables Used by Implicit Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Variables) for what those variables are and [Catalogue of Built-In Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) (or the output from `make -qp`) to see what the default rules that use those variables look like.